# How to only flatten the second level of a list of lists (to later turn it into a dictionary) in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

I have a list of lists which I later want to turn into a dictionary. The problem is that the list of lists is very irregular: For one key there exist between 1 and 4 lists with numbers that belong to that key. The original data set is stored in a json.
This is an example data set:

```
data = [36146779,
[17628,35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814],[51068348,49722,3255134,66598],[103475099, 1337536, 1136863360,257],
22971125,
[230806,116805,118456,9031, 3573662],[719279707,299836,40722,35134,668],[1337536, 1136863360,257],
111125168,
[719279707,299836,40722,35138],[17628,35633, 2847385],
71280747,
[806,116805,11845],[17628,35633, 2847385]]
```

I was able to completely flatten the list of lists, but I am stuck turning this flat list into a dictionary with the given keys

```
ex_eco = ["36146779","22971125","111125168","71280747"]
```

( I am sure it is also possible to directly turn the first nested list into a dictionary but I could not find a solution so I tried it this way)

```
def flatten(l):
  out = []
  for item in l:
    if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
      out.extend(flatten(item))
    else:
      out.append(item)
  return out

flattened_eco = flatten(data)

print(flattened_eco[0:100])
```

What I get is a flat list:

```
[36146779, 17628, 35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814, 51068348, 49722, 3255134, 66598, 103475099, 1337536, 1136863360, 257, 22971125, 230806, 116805, 118456, 9031, 3573662, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35134, 668, 1337536, 1136863360, 257, 111125168, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35138, 17628, 35633, 2847385, 71280747, 806, 116805, 11845, 17628, 35633, 2847385]
```

What I need is something like this:

```
[36146779,
[17628,35633, 2847385, 71393,41814,51068348,49722,3255134,66598,103475099,1337536, 1136863360,257],
22971125,
[230806,116805,118456,9031,573662,719279707,299836,40722,35134,668,1337536, 1136863360,257],
111125168,
[719279707,299836,40722,35138,17628,35633, 2847385],
71280747,
[806,116805,11845,17628,35633, 2847385]
]
```

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: Hi AdamGold, I need a list with they future keys and the future values, e.g. [36146779, [5,6,7,8], 434,[6,4,5,6], 57647[34,23,78,45]]. Please see the last section of my question for a better description.

Comment: Cory, yes you are right. I fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

def flatten(data):
    flattened = []
    for key, value in itertools.groupby(data, type):
        if key == int:
            flattened.append(next(value))
        else:
            flattened.append(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(value)))
    return flattened
```

Example

```
>>> data = [36146779,
            [17628,35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814],[51068348,49722,3255134,66598],[103475099, 1337536, 1136863360,257],
            22971125,
            [230806,116805,118456,9031, 3573662],[719279707,299836,40722,35134,668],[1337536, 1136863360,257],
            111125168,
            [719279707,299836,40722,35138],[17628,35633, 2847385],
            71280747,
            [806,116805,11845],[17628,35633, 2847385]]

>>> flatten(data)
[36146779, 
 [17628, 35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814, 51068348, 49722, 3255134, 66598, 103475099, 1337536, 1136863360, 257],
 22971125,
 [230806, 116805, 118456, 9031, 3573662, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35134, 668, 1337536, 1136863360, 257],
 111125168,
 [719279707, 299836, 40722, 35138, 17628, 35633, 2847385],
 71280747,
 [806, 116805, 11845, 17628, 35633, 2847385]]
```

To take this a step further and create a dictionary, just change the last line of the function to a `dict` comprehension

```
def dictify(data):
    flattened = []
    for key, value in itertools.groupby(data, type):
        if key == int:
            flattened.append(next(value))
        else:
            flattened.append(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(value)))
    return {key:value for key,value in zip(flattened[::2], flattened[1::2])}

>>> dictify(data)
{36146779: [17628, 35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814, 51068348, 49722, 3255134, 66598, 103475099, 1337536, 1136863360, 257],
 22971125: [230806, 116805, 118456, 9031, 3573662, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35134, 668, 1337536, 1136863360, 257],
 111125168: [719279707, 299836, 40722, 35138, 17628, 35633, 2847385],
 71280747: [806, 116805, 11845, 17628, 35633, 2847385]}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - Thank you! I will definitely have a look at the itertools package. Could you explain this `if key == int:` logic?

Comment: The function I passed to `groupby` was `type`. So when you loop over the groups, you'll get back pairs of `(key, group)`. Since I am grouping by `type` I want to handle the single `int` values differently than the `list` values, which are what I want to later flatten.

Answer (score 1):

From your input seems that you don't need a recursive function, just use an iteration:

```
result = {}
keys = []
for d in data:
  if type(d) == int:
    result[d] = []
    keys.append(d)
  else:
    result[keys[-1]] += d
```

Output using provided data:

```
{36146779: [17628, 35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814, 51068348, 49722, 3255134, 66598, 103475099, 1337536, 1136863360, 257], 22971125: [230806, 116805, 118456, 9031, 3573662, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35134, 668, 1337536, 1136863360, 257], 111125168: [719279707, 299836, 40722, 35138, 17628, 35633, 2847385], 71280747: [806, 116805, 11845, 17628, 35633, 2847385]}
```

Answer (score 1):

- [extend()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)- is used to merge two lists.

**Ex.**

```
data = [36146779,
[17628,35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814],[51068348,49722,3255134,66598],[103475099, 1337536, 1136863360,257],
22971125,
[230806,116805,118456,9031, 3573662],[719279707,299836,40722,35134,668],[1337536, 1136863360,257],
111125168,
[719279707,299836,40722,35138],[17628,35633, 2847385],
71280747,
[806,116805,11845],[17628,35633, 2847385]]

new_dict = {}
temp=None
for x in data:
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        new_dict[x] = []
        temp = x
    else:
        new_dict[temp].extend(x)

print(new_dict)
```

**O/P:**

```
{36146779: [17628, 35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814, 51068348, 49722, 3255134, 66598, 103475099, 1337536, 1136863360, 257], 22971125: [230806, 116805, 118456, 9031, 3573662, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35134, 668, 1337536, 1136863360, 257], 111125168: [719279707, 299836, 40722, 35138, 17628, 35633, 2847385], 71280747: [806, 116805, 11845, 17628, 35633, 2847385]}
```

Comment: Thanks bharatk, this code also works. just for learning purposes: what does the Temp=none do?

Comment: @TheresaS Initialize `None` value in `temp` variable, further, we use the `temp variable` as a `dictionary key`.

Answer (score 0):

One version using `itertools.groupby`:

```
data = [36146779,
[17628,35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814],[51068348,49722,3255134,66598],[103475099, 1337536, 1136863360,257],
22971125,
[230806,116805,118456,9031, 3573662],[719279707,299836,40722,35134,668],[1337536, 1136863360,257],
111125168,
[719279707,299836,40722,35138],[17628,35633, 2847385],
71280747,
[806,116805,11845],[17628,35633, 2847385]]

from itertools import groupby

def generate(d):
    for v, g in groupby(d, lambda k: isinstance(k, (tuple, list))):
        if not v:
            yield from g
        else:
            yield sum(g, [])

from pprint import pprint
pprint([*generate(data)], width=180)
```

Prints:

```
[36146779,
 [17628, 35633, 2847385, 71393, 41814, 51068348, 49722, 3255134, 66598, 103475099, 1337536, 1136863360, 257],
 22971125,
 [230806, 116805, 118456, 9031, 3573662, 719279707, 299836, 40722, 35134, 668, 1337536, 1136863360, 257],
 111125168,
 [719279707, 299836, 40722, 35138, 17628, 35633, 2847385],
 71280747,
 [806, 116805, 11845, 17628, 35633, 2847385]]
```